# C++, iterator question

Tags: c++, iterator

```
map <int, char*> testmap;
testmap[1] = "123";
testmap[2] = "007";
map<int, char*>::iterator p;

for(p = my_map.begin(); p != my_map.end(); p++) {
int len = strlen(p); // error here, why? thanks
cout << len << endl;
  cout << p->first << " : ";
  cout << p->second << endl;
}
```

I got error on this lie:  int len = strlen(p), I wang to get array's length.how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: you might want to use const size_t len = strlen( p.second ); instead

Comment: In addition to avoiding the warning as stijn suggests consider using const_iterator, prefix increment ++p, and assigning end() outside of loop for performance and style points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess what you mean is

```
strlen(p->second);
```

Answer (score 4):

Even better use std string:

```
map <int, std::string> testmap;
testmap[1] = "123";
testmap[2] = "007";
map<int, std::string>::iterator p;

for(p = testmap.begin(); p != testmap.end(); p++) {
    int len = p->second.size();
    cout << len << endl;
    cout << p->first << " : ";
    cout << p->second << endl;
}
```

Comment: +42:  For crap's sake, don't use old, crusty C-style `char*` strings with `map`s.  Actually, don't use them in C++ at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
strlen(p->second)
```

p is an iterator

Comment: i should say, p is a map iterator, so you have to explicitly point out that you want to find the length of the value

Comment: `p.second`?  Are you sure about that?

Comment: map iterators return an iterator of type pair<key,value>

Comment: map iterators return an address to the pair<key, value>

Answer (score 1):

```
map <int, char*> testmap;
testmap[1] = "123";
testmap[2] = "007";
map<int, char*>::iterator p;

for(p = my_map.begin(); p != my_map.end(); p++) {
    int len = std::iterator_traits<p>::value_type.size();
    cout << len << endl;
    cout << p->first << " : ";
    cout << p->second << endl;
}
```

Comment: Explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

p is an iterator for a pair key-value. And you need only value.